# Decode everything that is not defined as 'internal' or 'Web' to 'external' (oracle)

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to decode a columns with about 30 different possible values down to 3 values.

I want the decoded value to be `"internal"` if the original value is `"Interal KS & others",  or "Web"` if the original field is `"Webshop"`, all other values i want to decode as `"external"`.

Is this possible? or do i have to define a really long decode definition. I know it is possible to use `>` or `<` for numbers but how do i do "everything else" for text values?

Answer (score 1):

Oh... I actually read the answer before i posted the question, but didn't realize it. ><

Just use the "else" variable at the end.

```
DECODE(supplier_id, 10000, 'IBM',
                10001, 'Microsoft',
                10002, 'Hewlett Packard',
                'Gateway')
```

the last variable 'Gateway' is assigned to everything that is not defined with a new value in the decode function. So in my question above i used 'External' after defining `Internal` and `Web`.

Answer and example form here:
[Oracle / PLSQL: DECODE Function | techonthenet.com](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

It think this is much better (cleaner) done using a `CASE` statement:

```
case 
  when the_column in ('Interal KS & others', 'Web') then 'internal'
  else 'external'
end
```